# How to disable 'contentDescription' warning on gradle with lintOptions?

Tags: android, lint, android-lint

I would like to disable this warning:

> [Accessibility] Missing 'contentDescription' attribute on image

I know the solution `android:contentDescription:"@null"`. But I want to be able to do the entire project and not on each of my ImageView.

On [**documentation of tools android**](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings), they advocate to do it like this:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'TypographyFractions','TypographyQuotes'
        ...
    }
}
```

**My question is what is the name of lint options for this warning "contentDescription attribute on image"?**

---

**Edit, My Solution:**

Click on ***Suppress with @SuppressLint (Java) or tools:ignore (XML)***

This button add this on your `<ImageView .. />`:

```
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
```

So you just need to add this lintOptions on your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'ContentDescription'
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried ALT + Enter "Dont show warning again"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can disable it in your gradle config as well.
You can find a list of Lint issues [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks). If you check it the you can see that it contains the `TypographyFractions` and it contains also the `ContentDescription`. Please note that I didn't try them but I think it should work.

So in my opinion you should do it in the following way:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'ContentDescription'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution!  I don't want to do it for ALL projects, just certain ones that I know won't ever be used by blind people (like my own test apps).  This does the trick without having to put a line in every layout file.

Answer (score 1):

If not mistaken, you can disable them using Android Studio Preferences settings as follows:

Windows -> Preferences -> Inspection -> Uncheck "Image Without Content Description"

Try this [tutorial](http://www.kiodev.com/android-studio-lint-options/) to see how he has forced it to be converted to error. May be altering things here would fix it for you.